# Cannot connect to Azure from VS 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I am just getting started with Azure and one of the things I want to do is connect from VS 2013 to my Azure account in order to publish my web app. Unfortunately every time I try to connect I get back a long error message which is in HTML format but within a dialog box. The error starts with

> An error occurred during the sign in process: The Service Management
>   operation could not be authenticated

I tried everything but so far there is no way I can connect to Azure. Any ideas of what is going wrong?

Comment: why not publish by publish profile? you're new with azure it will be a lot easier to publish that way

Comment: Export profile from Azure Portal. Then import the file on the authentication screen while publishing from Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks I can publish the app easily by downloading the portal profile. Its just a pain that I cannot connect to Azure in the Server Explorer.